# how to change the offsetHeight of a element using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Hello i'm trying to change the offsetHeight of an element. i used the following

```
document.getElementById('id').style.offsetHeight = 0;
```

but i saw no visible change. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: And make sure element is **not** `inline` , use `block` or `inline-block` instead

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `offsetHeight` property indicates the height of the visible area for an element. It's a shorthand that contains the sum of dimensions from padding, scrollbars and borders.

However, it can't be used to change the actual size and as noted in comments, `offsetHeight` is a property of an element, not style.

To modify the actual size use `height`, `padding` or `border`.

Comment: And offsetHeight is a property of element, not its style object.

Answer (score 9):

You should set `style.height` to a string ending in `px`.

Answer (score 3):

You should set `style.height` and remember to add the unit at the end like 'px' , in the case you get it from `offsetHeight`for example (well you know what unit you need). It's style and you have all the different units ('px','%','em', 'vh', ...etc).
Here is an example:

```
myHeightInPx = 200;
DomElement.style.height = myHeightInPx + 'px';
```

Also to note is that offsetHeight return the height as a number, an integer. The unit is px. And if you get a value using it. you need always to add the unit 'px' when setting style.height, just like in above and the bellow example:

```
DomElement.style.height = AnotherDOMelment.offsetHeight() + 'px';
```