# Get div height with plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Any ideas on how to get a div's height without using jQuery?

I was searching Stack Overflow for this question and it seems like every answer is pointing to jQuery's `.height()`.

I tried something like `myDiv.style.height`, but it returned nothing, even when my div had its `width` and `height` set in CSS.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10118190/1172872

Answer (score 751, accepted):

```
var clientHeight = document.getElementById('myDiv').clientHeight;
```

or

```
var offsetHeight = document.getElementById('myDiv').offsetHeight;
```

[`clientHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight) includes padding.

[`offsetHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight) includes padding, scrollBar and borders.

Comment: offsetheight doesnt wokr on ie10 below http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/tableViewport_desktop.html

Comment: You could also use `scrollHeight` which includes the height of the contained document, vertical padding, and vertical borders.

Comment: `clientHeight` also includes padding, so it's not equivalent to `$.height()`

Comment: NOTE: This allows you to get the height of something, but you cannot change the height of your element with it. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925217/how-to-change-the-offsetheight-of-a-element-using-javascript

Answer (score 39):

Another option is to use the getBoundingClientRect function.  Please note that getBoundingClientRect will return an empty rect if the element's display is 'none'.

Example:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("myDiv");
if(elem) {
  var rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  console.log("height: " + rect.height);  
}
```

UPDATE:
Here is the same code written in 2020:

```
const elem = document.querySelector("#myDiv");
if(elem) {
  const rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  console.log(`height: ${rect.height}`);
}
```

Answer (score 27):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zFTMX/)

```
var element = document.getElementById('element');
alert(element.offsetHeight);
```

Answer (score 18):

1. [HTMLElement.style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) - returns defined Style of element
2. [clientHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight) - height + padding
3. [offsetHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight) - height + padding + borders
4. [scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight) - return height + padding
5. [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) - return left, top, right, bottom, x, y,
   width, and height properties
6. [getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) - returns all CSS properties of an element

```js
// returns defined Style of element
const styleHeight = document.getElementById('myDiv').style.height;
console.log('style Height : ', styleHeight);

// height + padding
const clientHeight = document.getElementById('myDiv').clientHeight;
console.log('client Height : ', clientHeight);

// height + padding + borders
const offsetHeight = document.getElementById('myDiv').offsetHeight;
console.log('offset Height : ', offsetHeight);

// height + padding
const scrollHeight = document.getElementById('myDiv').scrollHeight;
console.log('scroll Height : ', scrollHeight);

// return left, top, right, bottom, x, y, width, and height properties
const getBoundingClientRectHeight = document.getElementById('myDiv').getBoundingClientRect().height;
console.log('get Bounding Client Rect Height : ', getBoundingClientRectHeight);

// returns all CSS properties of an element
const styleElementHeight = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("myDiv")).height;
console.log('style Element Height : ', styleElementHeight);
```

```html
<div id="myDiv" style="margin:10px;padding:20px;height:200px;">
    <input type="Text">
    <input type="button" value="submit">
</div>
```

Answer (score 13):

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv'); //get #myDiv
alert(myDiv.clientHeight);
```

clientHeight and clientWidth are what you are looking for.

offsetHeight and offsetWidth also return the height and width but it includes the border and scrollbar. Depending on the situation, you can use one or the other.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

The other answers weren't working for me. Here's what I found at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_height.asp), assuming the `div` has a `height` and/or `width` set.

All you need is `height` and `width` to exclude padding.

```
    var height = document.getElementById('myDiv').style.height;
    var width = document.getElementById('myDiv').style.width;
```

Comment: I can't see how w3schools says the other methods aren't accurate.

Comment: @aknuds1 Never said they weren't accurate. They just weren't getting the job done for some reason so I kept looking and found this.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to `el.clientHeight` and `el.offsetHeight`, when you need the **height of the content inside the element** (regardless of the height set on the element itself) you can use `el.scrollHeight`. [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22675563/661643)

This can be useful if you want to set the element height or max-height to the exact height of it's internal dynamic content. For example:

```
var el = document.getElementById('myDiv')

el.style.maxHeight = el.scrollHeight+'px'
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
myDiv.offsetHeight
```

```js
console.log("Height:", myDiv.offsetHeight );
```

```css
#myDiv { width: 100px; height: 666px; background: red}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Best way is -

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');

var myDivWidth = myDiv.clientWidth || myDiv.offsetWidth || (myDiv.getBoundingClientRect()).width;
var myDivHeight= myDiv.clientHeight || myDiv.offsetHeight  || (myDiv.getBoundingClientRect()).height;
          
console.log("Width: "+ myDivWidth + "px");
console.log("Height: "+ myDivHeight + "px");
```

```html
<div style="padding: 50px; margin: 8px auto; outline: 1px solid green;">

  <div id="myDiv" style="width: 100%; height: 256px; padding: 50px; margin: 4px; background: #000000; color: #ffffff; outline: 1px solid red;">
  This is "#myDiv" <br>
  Width: 100% <br>
  Height: 256px
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Here's one more alternative:

```
var classElements = document.getElementsByClassName("className");

function setClassHeight (classElements, desiredHeightValue) 
    {
        var arrayElements = Object.entries(classElements);
        for(var i = 0; i< arrayElements.length; i++) {
            arrayElements[i][1].style.height = desiredHeightValue;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

One option would be

```
const styleElement = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("myDiv"));
console.log(styleElement.height);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="item">show taille height</div>
<script>
    alert(document.getElementById('item').offsetHeight);
</script>
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mouadh/ef6v7a36/)

Answer (score 1):

javascript height computation

include padding

use `clientHeight`

```
element.clientHeight
```

use `offsetHeight`

include padding,borders,border_width

```
element.offsetHeight
```

use `el.style.height`

It return given height only(must have manual height eg: `<div style="height:12px"></div>` otherwise it return empty result

```
element.style.height
```

use `getBoundingClientRect`

includes padding,border,border_width

```
elem.getBoundingClientRect();
elem.height
```