# How to show div property that is in a class with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Following an example: http://jsfiddle.net/UcQ39/

HTML:

```
<div id="test" class="test">Test</div>
```

CSS:

```
.test{height: 90px; border: 1px solid black;}
```

Javascript:

```
alert(document.getElementById('test').style.height);
```

I want to show the `height` or another property of the div but the alert is empty. How to solve? The height is in a class, i don't want to move it in a id.

Comment: please, post the code also in your question

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS / JavaScript - How do you get the rendered height of an element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526347/css-javascript-how-do-you-get-the-rendered-height-of-an-element)

Comment: `getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('test')).height` [window.getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle)

Comment: With plain javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615552/get-div-height-with-plain-javascript

Comment: Or you can use jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/height/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('test').style.height
```

Refers to the `height` property defined in a `style` attribute.

But in your code you have not a style attribute, so you can get the total height of the element with

```
document.getElementById('test').offsetHeight 
/* return 92 (90 + 2px borders ) */
```

or (if you also need to read other properties)

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('test')).getPropertyValue("height")
/* return "90px" */
```

Comment: And if it's not height but z-index?

Comment: downvoter cares to explain downvote? So I can improve my answer

Answer (score 0):

`element.style` reads element's `style` property.

If you had `<div style="height:100px">` you could read its `.style.height`.

To get what's specified by CSS you should use `getComputedStyle` method, but for dimensions it would be best to use `offsetHeight` / `offsetWidth`.

BTW: reading from `style` property or using `getComputedStyle` gives you the value and the unit, which may be "10px" or "2%" or "7em" and is pretty much useless if you need the pixel dimensions of an element.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
document.getElementById('test').offsetHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much idea about these emulators. But when you put your javascript on page load, the javascript gets called first. And then the page elements gets set.

If you want this alert in your code, add the `<script>` tag after `<html>` tag and write your alert in that. This should work.