# Set div height with javascript from another div height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two divs side by side. Neither of them has a standart height, but the first one has content when the other one fill with content after a form submition. I want to set the height of the second one the same with the first one.

Here is the html:

```
<div id='left'>
...........
</div>
<div id='right'>
...........
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready ( function(){

    var divHeight = document.getElementById('left').style.height;
    document.getElementById('right').style.height = divHeight+'px';
    });​
</script>
```

I don't have any error on the console, but the height of the second div doesn't change. Any help?

Comment: Yes, because `style.height` will return the inline CSS style and not the computed height of the element.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're looking for the `offsetHeight`. The `height` property of your leftmost div is not set (because that's the actual CSS property, and you're not setting the height statically), but the `offsetHeight` is the actual height of the div as defined by its contents.

```
var offsetHeight = document.getElementById('left').offsetHeight;
document.getElementById('right').style.height = offsetHeight+'px';
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6gERe/) to demonstrate.

Note that there is also `clientHeight`. The difference is that `offsetHeight` also includes padding and borders. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15615701/1711232) as well.

Comment: I tried it before, but without a success. Do you know if I have a problem because the `right` div is a well from Twitter-Bootstrap?

Comment: That should not be a problem. In fact, have a look at this updated fiddle that includes `right` as a well - it seems to work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/6gERe/1/ There must have been something else causing harm, then..

Comment: It was a typo. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using jQuery. Here's the jQuery version that is equivalent of the native JavaScript code that you used.

```
$(document).ready ( function(){
 var divHeight = $('#left').height();
 $('#right').height(divHeight);
});
```

[Demo ( JsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/subins2000/wyzpW/).

Since you're using `left` and `right` as the elements' Id, I assume they are `inline-block`s. So you should set the offset height of the other one than the real height :

```
$(document).ready ( function(){
 var divHeight = $('#left')[0].offsetHeight;
 $('#right').height(divHeight);
});
```

[Demo (JsFiddle).](http://jsfiddle.net/subins2000/wyzpW/3/)

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery

```
$(document).ready ( function(){
    var leftHeight = $('#left').height();

    $('#right').height(leftHeight);
});
```

or directly

```
$(document).ready ( function(){
  $('#right').height( $('#left').height() );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a **helper** function that accepts a jquery object with **multiple objects** to set the height equal.
check it out...https://gist.github.com/rob-bar/10283279
Advantages are that the functionality is isolated so you can make a list of things to check when you have more divs than 2 or divs in divs that you want ....etc...

BUT! be aware of the fact that you can accomplish equal heights with either **flexbox** or with **display: table and cell** on the child.