# vertical align middle content with bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to set vertical middle content in div block with latest bootstrap **v3.2.0**.

I have Read the answer to [vertical-align with bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547819/vertical-align-with-bootstrap-3), but it uses `float:none;` in div block.

However, I **can't** use `float:none;` in div block according to our layout.

**I have this code:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-4">....</div>
  <div class="col-lg-5">....</div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">....</div>
</div>
```

Content Height is dynamic in block 1. I want to set vertical middle content in block 2 and 3 according to block 1 height.

**This is how our layout currently looks:**

```
       Block 1           Block 2            Block 3
 ------------------ ------------------ ------------------
|  Content Height  |      Content     |      Content     |
|        is        |------------------ ------------------
|     Dynamic      | 
 ------------------
```

**if, I will use `float:none;` So, This is Our layout looks:**

```
       Block 1           Block 2        
 ------------------ ------------------ 
|  Content Height  |                  |
|        is        |      Content     |
|     Dynamic      |                  |
 ------------------ ------------------ 
       Block 3
 ------------------
|      Content     |
 ------------------
```

**This is how I would like it to look:**

```
       Block 1           Block 2            Block 3
 ------------------ ------------------ ------------------
|  Content Height  |                  |                  |
|        is        |      Content     |      Content     |
|     Dynamic      |                  |                  |
 ------------------ ------------------ ------------------
```

Comment: You can apply equal height function of jquery

Comment: If you wat I can give you solution with JQUery

Comment: Find out the height of a div at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615552/get-div-height-with-plain-javascript and place in "Block 2" and in "Block 3" and some other css will make align vertical center.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the best way to achieve that is to create a table layout within the container:

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/StephanWagner/Zn79G/9/embedded/result

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="table-container">
    <div class="col-table-cell col-lg-4">A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A<br>A</div>
    <div class="col-table-cell col-lg-5">B</div>
    <div class="col-table-cell col-lg-3">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
@media (min-width: 1200px) {

     .table-container {
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .table-container .col-table-cell {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        float: none;
    }
}
```

The media query makes sure the content will only be a table in large displays, otherwise it will stack as it used to.

Comment: Thats exactly what you achieve with this: http://jsfiddle.net/StephanWagner/Zn79G/1/embedded/result/
To make this work for wur layout change the -md- classes back to -lg- and change the ```min-width: 992px``` to ```min-width: 1200px```

Comment: Here is an updated fiddle with a large layout:
http://jsfiddle.net/StephanWagner/Zn79G/4/embedded/result/
Make sure to move your screen to over 1200px in width

Comment: Thanks, but, If, i will use this code so, it is not work. any solution. `<div class="col-md-4">A<br>A<br>A<br>A</div>
    <div class="col-md-5">B</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">C</div>`

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle or a link where I can see why it is not working in your code? (Remember to add the ```<div class="table-container">```). The problem is that a vertical-align set to middle is only really working in a table cell, and a table-cell can not have a float.

Comment: Here you go, works like a charm: http://jsfiddle.net/StephanWagner/Zn79G/9/embedded/result/

Comment: one more issue create. please see this maybe, you can help me.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25159115/image-max-width-not-working-in-firefox/25159417#25159417

Comment: Hi, again, if, i use Push/pull columns in this code. So, not work Push/pull. any possibility there.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
.container > div {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**[bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/E9ejOMpdzP)**

Comment: ... but I cannot use `float:none;` in a div block according to our layout.

Comment: Then I don't see another way to do it. Why can't you use float:none on this one div?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. That's not my restriction; it was a quote from OP. It seems OP knows how to do it when using `float:none`

Comment: @j08691 I have update Our question. I hope, You can clearly understand now.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 14rem;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.jumbotron {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  border: 1px dashed deeppink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container theme-showcase" role="main">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    I want to center this div with Bootstrap.
  </div>
</div>
```

[Get from [Solved] Vertically center with Bootstrap](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/vertically-center-with-bootstrap/)

Comment: you should put some explanations

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the solution with bootstrap 3: http://jsfiddle.net/raffi/52VtD/7348/

```css
.col-lg-4 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: I have update Our question. I hope, You can clearly understand now.