# Image max-width not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here, I am using latest bootstrap v3.2.0

When I have call `display: table-cell;` CSS in div block. So, Will not work `max-width: 100%;` CSS for inside image of it div block in Firefox. It is working fine in Other browser.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Q7742/2/embedded/result/

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="table-container">
<div class="col-table-cell col-lg-4"><img src="//farm1.staticflickr.com/22/28331349_fd0fbadbbd_z.jpg?zz=1"></div>
<div class="col-table-cell col-lg-5">B</div>
<div class="col-table-cell col-lg-3">C</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.col-table-cell.col-lg-5 {
    background: #ddffdd;
}
.col-table-cell.col-lg-3 {
    background: #ffffdd;
}

img {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;    
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
.table-container {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .table-container .col-table-cell {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        float: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be the same issue, like this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923710/why-do-firefox-and-opera-ignore-max-width-inside-of-display-table-cell

Comment: The problem is that the table cells have no widths defined, so the img should be 100% of, what?

Comment: @MrLister Here, i have using bootstrap v3.2.0 so, there already width define in percentage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your table needs to be fixed for it to work in firefox:

Updated Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Q7742/6/embedded/result/

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .table-container {
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .table-container .col-table-cell {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        float: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float: none;` that is like below one.

```
.table-container .col-table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: if, I will remove `float: none;` So, content is not vertical middle. I work with this- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25140284/vertical-align-middle-content-with-bootstrap-3/25140454#25140454