# Angular directive works with inline style but not with class

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this directive:

```
angular.module('exampleApp').directive('exampleDirective', ['$document', '$window', function($document, $window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: false,
        template: '<div class="foo"></div>',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            var targetElement = angular.element(document.querySelector($attrs['targetSelector']));
            console.log(targetElement.css('height'));
        }
   }
]);
```

Which works fine with this html:

```
 <div id="div1" style="height: 100px">A div</div>
 <example-directive target-selector="#div1" />
```

Because in the console I see: "100px" printed out

But with this html:

```
 <style>
      .div-example {
          height: 100px;
      }
 </style>

 <div id="div2" class="div-example">A div</div>
 <example-directive target-selector="#div2" />
```

Which is basically the same but without inline-style, the directive is simply not working. The console is printing: "" (empty string).

How do I solve this?
I tried `scope: true` but it didn't work either.
Is `targetElement.css('height')` only good for inline style?

Comment: id="#div2" should be id="div2"

Comment: yeah that was a typo when writing the question, sorry... the real code doesn't have that typo. I've fixed the code in the question.

Comment: jqlite - css - Only retrieves inline-styles, does not call getComputedStyle() - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#css()

Comment: fyi - [clientHeight or offsetHeight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615552/get-div-height-with-plain-javascript) is way to go - http://plnkr.co/edit/HU2l3gkMeotndxVCEHON?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `.css('height')`, jQuery can tell you only the values set in the element's `style` property or attribute.

If you want to know the actual height of an element, try with

```
targetElement[0].clientHeight
```

Or with jQuery:

```
targetElement.height()
```

See the difference explained a bit better here: https://api.jquery.com/height/

Comment: but i'm not even using jquery... this is the angular's own jqLite (i think that is how its called)

Comment: also `targetElement.clientHeight` is giving me undefined

Comment: Sorry, should have specified it better.  your `targetElement` is a jqlite object and clientHeight is a property of the actual DOM element.  use `.height()` or do `.get(0).clientHeight`

Comment: Marked as accepted although I ended up using this: `window.getComputedStyle(targetElement[0], null).getPropertyValue("height")`, because I needed the computed height, not the `clientHeight` nor the `offsetHeight`