# How to make div take all the height available?

Tags: javascript, css

I have this HTML:

```
<div>
  <span></span>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

The Span can take up one or more lines (depends on the text it has and size of the Div). I want the Textarea to take all of the height left in div.

Please no jQuery.

https://jsfiddle.net/ntme8Lt4/

Comment: Can you show us an example of the problem you're having in jsfiddle.net?

Comment: It all depends on what you are trying to do and what browser support you need. Do you have a fiddle on what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Tek: I added a fiddle. As you can see textarea takes too much height.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space?rq=1

Comment: What browser are you using? The textarea is using all the space that the span isn't using.

Comment: @Tek the newest Firefox. It uses MORE space and gets outside the border of DIV.

Comment: @Paulie_D I think flex could solve the problem, but it doesn't work below IE10 so it's an unacceptable solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to the "possible duplicate" I came up with this solution:

```
<div>
  <span>Hello<br>World</span>
    <b><textarea></textarea></b>
</div>

div
{
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid red;   
    display: table;
}
span
{
    display: block;
    background-color: red;
}
b
{    

    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table-row;
}
textarea
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;    
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c42go079/

Answer (score 2):

The CSS/style tag for that would just be max-height:100%; and width:100%;

This would hold the div's size constant if it is set to a percentage of its parent container or a constant value like 900px.

Since the size of span is not known, just leave it unspecified so it auto-sizes to content.

Comment: I don't see how max-height helps me here. Please see: https://jsfiddle.net/ntme8Lt4/

Answer (score 2):

There's a circular issue here - the height of the div is (normally) determined by the size of its components. You need something to break the circle and determine the height of either the div or the text area.

Comment: The height of div is set.

Comment: I think there's no option other than using JS, along the lines proposed by @brso05, as the height of the span is unknown at design time. Flex could work here, but it's not supported enough (sadly). The 100% value of the height and the width refer to the parent div's dimensions, not to the available space.

Answer (score 2):

You can use offsetHeight to get the heights of the different elements, and from there it is just a calculation of the container - span element to find the remaining.

```
document.querySelector('textarea').style.height = (document.querySelector('div').offsetHeight-document.querySelector('span').offsetHeight)+'px'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rhbritton/4eck8dua/1/

Answer (score 2):

If you're just wanting to use pure CSS and without the needs of tables etc you could try this approach.

HTML:

```
<div>
   <span>
       Hello<br>
       Hello<br>
       Hello
   </span>
   <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
span {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    background-color: red;
}
textarea {      
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mzb08xy6/)

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: That's almost right. If textarea has visible scrollbars then they are cut.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `clientWidth` and `clientHeight` if your willing to use pure JS:

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/00gbmL9f/24/)

```
function test()
{ 
    var div = document.getElementById("testDiv");
    var span = document.getElementById("testSpan");
    var textArea = document.getElementById("testTextArea");
    var height = div.clientHeight - span.clientHeight;
    textArea.style.height = (height - 5) + "px";
    textArea.style.width = (div.clientWidth - 5) + "px";
}

test();
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15615701/4028085)

Comment: @Tom if you don't want to wrap with `<b>` tag here is a solution using plain JS.

Answer (score 0):

you can use flex

```
div
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; /*layout top to bottom*/
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid red;    
}
span
{
    display: block;
    background-color: red;
}
textarea
{    
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    flex-grow: 1; /*take up remaining space in flex container*/
}
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ntme8Lt4/13/