# Where is the default size of a div element defined or calculated?

Tags: html, css

I wonder how a browser calculates the initial `height` and `width` values for `div` elements without a given size. Given this `div` for example:

```
<div>
  TEST
</div>
```

My browser (Chrome) calculates the size of this div to 1255 x 18, with a windowsize of 1271 x 284. It seems like `div`s default to the height of a line and the inner width of the window minus some. But I would like to know more about it.

I couldn't find anything here:
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-div-element

Where can I find this kind of information?

Comment: Inline elements has the size of the content inside, block elements has the full size

Comment: If JS counts, here is your solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15615701/4060922

Comment: Chrome's default styling puts `margin: 8px` on `body`, so that's where the `16px` between 1255 and 1271 are going.

Comment: Do you mean the viewport size? Because the window size often takes into account the scrollbar, window frames, and the browser chrome (with a lowercase c).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`div` tags are **block level elements**. All block level elements inherit the width of their parent element by default.

In your example, the `div` is inheriting the width of the parent `body` tag, taking into account any margin or padding on the body element.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) is usually a great source of information for this sort of thing - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements

Comment: this doesn't mention height. Which is max(0,content).

Answer (score 11):

It has `display: block` so `width` is `100%`, `height` is `auto` so it's the size of whatever's inside.

Comment: width 100% can outgrow the container if there are paddings and box sizing is content-box, while leaving width not set does not outgrow the container.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#the-page), a default value of 8px is expected to be used for the margin.

> For each property in the table below (`margin-top`, `margin-right`,`margin-bottom`,`margin-left`), given a body element, the first attribute that exists maps to the pixel length property on the body element. If none of the attributes for a property are found, or if the value of the attribute that was found cannot be parsed successfully, then a default value of **8px** is expected to be used for that property instead.

That is why your `width` is 1255 which is (1271 - 8 * 2). The heigh is the from the content -- `TEST`.

I have created a slightly more complex example:

```
<body>
<div id="outer">
  <div style="display:inline">
    <div id="inner">
      X
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

#### Body

[image: default size of a div]

#### Outer div

[image: outer div]

#### Inline div

[image: inline div]

#### Inner div

[image]

Answer (score 1):

All block level elements takes the available width of their parent.

Comment: you could have wrote this in comment