# How To Make Next Scene Insert Below Instead of Having It Create A New Page

Tags: javascript, cordova

Basically, I'm making a text game. The problem is whenever you click on the button, it makes it a whole new page. I want to insert the new scene below the old, like a texting app. I cannot figure it out no matter what I do, I keep breaking the Javascript.

```
//these variables connect our code with the 'id' on the html
//we can then manipulate the variables and it will manipulate the html
var images = document.getElementById("images"); 
var text = document.getElementById("text"); 
var buttonBox = document.getElementById('buttonBox');
var input = document.getElementById('input');
//this is the variable for the name of the character
var hero;



//this is how after we type in the character name and hit enter
//we will add the name to the variable, remove the input box and start our first scenario
input.onkeypress = function(event) {
  console.log(input.value);
  if (event.key == "Enter" || event.keyCode == 13) {
    hero =  input.value;
    input.parentNode.removeChild(input)
    advanceTo(scenario.two)
  }
};


//this changes the text and puts in your characters name
var changeText = function(words) {
  text.innerHTML = words.replace("Your dog", hero);
};

//this takes the image link and puts it in the proper format, sending it to the html
var changeImage = function(img) {
  images.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + img + ")";
};


//this looks at the number of options we have set and creates enough buttons 
var changeButtons = function(buttonList) {
  buttonBox.innerHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < buttonList.length; i++) {
    buttonBox.innerHTML += "<button onClick="+buttonList[i][1]+">" + buttonList[i][0] + "</button>";
  };
};

//this is what moves the game along
var advanceTo = function(s) {
  changeImage(s.image)
  changeText(s.text)
  changeButtons(s.buttons)
};






//this is the object that holds each scenario, the more you add the more options there are
//scenario = {}
var scenario = {
  one: {
    image: "http://s9.postimg.org/eceo9mp73/5860028206_d66810105f_b.jpg", //dog
    text: "H-hello? Yes! Yes! It's working! Is anyone there? Hello? If you're there, what's your name?",
  },
  two: {
    image: "http://s9.postimg.org/9p8m7v1u7/6899639786_d517c4cce3_z.jpg", //house
    text: "Your dog yanks at the leash. You hear dogs barking and see an old abandoned house. Strangely, the door is wide open. What do you want to do?",
    buttons: [["Turn and run", "advanceTo(scenario.three)"],["Enter The House", "advanceTo(scenario.four)"]]
  },
  three: {
    image: "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-83pWE4JxQxM/ViiOd_7nGTI/AAAAAAAADUg/yCJ8iAB-gMY/s1600/postapoc5.jpg",//"http://s4.postimg.org/t1g20apst/261819008_d4316c1bdf_o.jpg",
    text: "A wild gang of rabid dogs are gaining on you. Against your better judgement you enter the creepy house for saftey. Your dog is whincing and may be injured.",
    buttons: [["continue", "advanceTo(scenario.four)"]]
  },
    four: {
    image: "http://s6.postimg.org/kz5m1cnkh/2919478782_c343d14be6_b.jpg",
    text: "Your dog has run, barking loudly, into the basement. You wonder what's down there. The door jammed when you slammed it behind you. You are going to need something to pry it back open",
    buttons: [["Follow your Dog Downstairs", "advanceTo(scenario.five)"],["Search the Kitchen for a knife", "advanceTo(scenario.five)"]]
  },
    five: {
    image: "http://s6.postimg.org/kz5m1cnkh/2919478782_c343d14be6_b.jpg",
    text: "TO BE CONTINUED...",

  },

};


//this is the code that starts the game
advanceTo(scenario.one);
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>The Help</title>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">


</head>

<body>
  <html>

  <body>
    <div id="images">
    </div>
    <div id="text">
    </div>

    <input id="input" onkeydown='submitDogName(this)' placeholder='What is your name?'>
    <div id="buttonBox">
    </div>

  </body>

</html>

    <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

What would make it so instead of changing to a complete different page, it inserts it below, again like a message?

Comment: Plz also provide `HTML` code.

Comment: Added :) @Anson

Answer (score 0):

There are some problem you must deal with. See as below.

1. Must add a condition for `falsy` value like `undefined`. See the following modification.

   ```
   var changeButtons = function(buttonList) {
     if(!buttonList) return; // Here.
     buttonBox.innerHTML = "";
     for (var i = 0; i < buttonList.length; i++) {
       buttonBox.innerHTML += "<button onClick="+buttonList[i][1]+">" + buttonList[i][0] + "</button>";
     };
   };
   ```
2. Use single quote to quote value of `url` in background image. See the following modification.

   ```
   var changeImage = function(img) {
     images.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img + "')"; // Here.
   };
   ```
3. The height of `div` element is 0 if there is no content inside so you have to set height a specific value by **CSS** or **JavaScript**. You can see the default size of `div` element from [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35010655/where-is-the-default-size-of-a-div-element-defined-or-calculated). See below **CSS** content.

   ```
   #images {
     background-size: 100% 100%;
     height: 200px;
   }
   ```

Now, you can see the complete example as below and you may realize `onkeydown='submitDogName(this)'` will throw exception so I removed it. The below example is just a executable demo at the moment. You can see **EDIT** for the version of texting APP which you may need.

```js
//these variables connect our code with the 'id' on the html
//we can then manipulate the variables and it will manipulate the html
var images = document.getElementById("images"); 
var text = document.getElementById("text"); 
var buttonBox = document.getElementById('buttonBox');
var input = document.getElementById('input');
//this is the variable for the name of the character
var hero;

//this is how after we type in the character name and hit enter
//we will add the name to the variable, remove the input box and start our first scenario
input.onkeypress = function(event) {
  if (event.key == "Enter" || event.keyCode == 13) {
    hero = input.value;
    input.parentNode.removeChild(input)
    advanceTo(scenario.two)
  }
};

//this changes the text and puts in your characters name
var changeText = function(words) {
  text.innerHTML = words.replace("Your dog", hero);
};

//this takes the image link and puts it in the proper format, sending it to the html
var changeImage = function(img) {
  images.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img + "')";
};

//this looks at the number of options we have set and creates enough buttons 
var changeButtons = function(buttonList) {
  if(!buttonList) return;
  buttonBox.innerHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < buttonList.length; i++) {
    buttonBox.innerHTML += "<button onClick="+buttonList[i][1]+">" + buttonList[i][0] + "</button>";
  };
};

//this is what moves the game along
var advanceTo = function(s) {
  changeImage(s.image)
  changeText(s.text)
  changeButtons(s.buttons)
};

//this is the object that holds each scenario, the more you add the more options there are
//scenario = {}
var scenario = {
  one: {
    image: "http://s9.postimg.org/eceo9mp73/5860028206_d66810105f_b.jpg", //dog
    text: "H-hello? Yes! Yes! It's working! Is anyone there? Hello? If you're there, what's your name?",
  },
  two: {
    image: "http://s9.postimg.org/9p8m7v1u7/6899639786_d517c4cce3_z.jpg", //house
    text: "Your dog yanks at the leash. You hear dogs barking and see an old abandoned house. Strangely, the door is wide open. What do you want to do?",
    buttons: [["Turn and run", "advanceTo(scenario.three)"],["Enter The House", "advanceTo(scenario.four)"]]
  },
  three: {
    image: "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-83pWE4JxQxM/ViiOd_7nGTI/AAAAAAAADUg/yCJ8iAB-gMY/s1600/postapoc5.jpg",//"http://s4.postimg.org/t1g20apst/261819008_d4316c1bdf_o.jpg",
    text: "A wild gang of rabid dogs are gaining on you. Against your better judgement you enter the creepy house for saftey. Your dog is whincing and may be injured.",
    buttons: [["continue", "advanceTo(scenario.four)"]]
  },
    four: {
    image: "http://s6.postimg.org/kz5m1cnkh/2919478782_c343d14be6_b.jpg",
    text: "Your dog has run, barking loudly, into the basement. You wonder what's down there. The door jammed when you slammed it behind you. You are going to need something to pry it back open",
    buttons: [["Follow your Dog Downstairs", "advanceTo(scenario.five)"],["Search the Kitchen for a knife", "advanceTo(scenario.five)"]]
  },
    five: {
    image: "http://s6.postimg.org/kz5m1cnkh/2919478782_c343d14be6_b.jpg",
    text: "TO BE CONTINUED...",

  },

};

//this is the code that starts the game
advanceTo(scenario.one);
```

```css
#images {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <title>The Help</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *"/>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="images">
  </div>
  <div id="text">
  </div>

  <input id="input" placeholder='What is your name?'>
  <div id="buttonBox">
  </div>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

I think this is what you look for. Check it and tell me whether it is or not.

```js
//these variables connect our code with the 'id' on the html
//we can then manipulate the variables and it will manipulate the html
var images = document.getElementById("images"); 
var text = document.getElementById("text"); 
var buttonBox = document.getElementById('buttonBox');
var input = document.getElementById('input');
//this is the variable for the name of the character
var hero;

//this is how after we type in the character name and hit enter
//we will add the name to the variable, remove the input box and start our first scenario
input.onkeypress = function(event) {
  if (event.key == "Enter" || event.keyCode == 13) {
    hero = input.value;
    input.parentNode.removeChild(input)
    advanceTo(scenario.two)
  }
};

//this changes the text and puts in your characters name
var changeText = function(words) {
  text.innerHTML = words.replace("Your dog", hero);
};

//this takes the image link and puts it in the proper format, sending it to the html
var changeImage = function(img) {
  images.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img + "')";
};

//this looks at the number of options we have set and creates enough buttons 
var changeButtons = function(buttonList) {
  if(!buttonList) return;
  buttonBox.innerHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < buttonList.length; i++) {
    buttonBox.innerHTML += "<button onClick="+buttonList[i][1]+">" + buttonList[i][0] + "</button>";
  };
};

var appendHistory = function() {
  var historyDiv = document.getElementById("history");
  var historyItemDiv = document.createElement("div");
  historyItemDiv.appendChild(images.cloneNode(true));
  historyDiv.appendChild(historyItemDiv);
}

//this is what moves the game along
var advanceTo = function(s) {
  changeImage(s.image)
  changeText(s.text)
  changeButtons(s.buttons)
  if(!s.isLast) appendHistory();
};

//this is the object that holds each scenario, the more you add the more options there are
//scenario = {}
var scenario = {
  one: {
    image: "http://s9.postimg.org/eceo9mp73/5860028206_d66810105f_b.jpg", //dog
    text: "H-hello? Yes! Yes! It's working! Is anyone there? Hello? If you're there, what's your name?",
    isLast: false
  },
  two: {
    image: "http://s9.postimg.org/9p8m7v1u7/6899639786_d517c4cce3_z.jpg", //house
    text: "Your dog yanks at the leash. You hear dogs barking and see an old abandoned house. Strangely, the door is wide open. What do you want to do?",
    buttons: [["Turn and run", "advanceTo(scenario.three)"],["Enter The House", "advanceTo(scenario.four)"]],
    isLast: false
  },
  three: {
    image: "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-83pWE4JxQxM/ViiOd_7nGTI/AAAAAAAADUg/yCJ8iAB-gMY/s1600/postapoc5.jpg",//"http://s4.postimg.org/t1g20apst/261819008_d4316c1bdf_o.jpg",
    text: "A wild gang of rabid dogs are gaining on you. Against your better judgement you enter the creepy house for saftey. Your dog is whincing and may be injured.",
    buttons: [["continue", "advanceTo(scenario.four)"]],
    isLast: false
  },
  four: {
    image: "http://s6.postimg.org/kz5m1cnkh/2919478782_c343d14be6_b.jpg",
    text: "Your dog has run, barking loudly, into the basement. You wonder what's down there. The door jammed when you slammed it behind you. You are going to need something to pry it back open",
    buttons: [["Follow your Dog Downstairs", "advanceTo(scenario.five)"],["Search the Kitchen for a knife", "advanceTo(scenario.five)"]],
    isLast: false
  },
  five: {
    image: "http://s6.postimg.org/kz5m1cnkh/2919478782_c343d14be6_b.jpg",
    text: "TO BE CONTINUED...",
    isLast: true
  },

};

//this is the code that starts the game
advanceTo(scenario.one);
```

```css
#images {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

#history > div:last-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>The Help</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="history"></div>
    <div id="images"></div>
    <div id="text"></div>
    <input id="input" placeholder='What is your name?'/>
    <div id="buttonBox"></div>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you click the buttons, they still create new pages, they're not inserted below... @anson

Comment: Do you mean the flash when switching images?

Comment: Or do you want a user story?

Comment: run the code snippet and you'll see what i mean by it making a whole new window and simply not inserting the next part below it @anson

Comment: I don't get it. Could you provide the result you expect?

Comment: Okay. I think I know what you want. What you want is appending contents into the old content, right?