# MaterialUI Box takes over background image

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a react component that contains a forms and it is formatted as follows:

```
<Box
      display="flex"
      justifyContent="center"
      alignItems="center"
      style={{ minHeight: "100vh", backgroundColor: "gray", opacity: "0.8" }}
    > ...
</Box>
```

This componenent, called Form is then passed in `App.js` as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import Form from "./components/Form";

const sectionStyle = {
  height: "100vh",

  backgroundImage:
    "url('www.blablabla.com/img.jpg') ",

  backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
  backgroundSize: "cover"
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div style={sectionStyle}>
      <Form />
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

However, the results I get is this one:

[image]

I added the opacity to better show that my `Box` component is 'stretched' all over the window, while I would like it to just wrap its content, so that if some opacity is applied, it will only appear I side the `Box`, and the background image will be normal.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

material-ui Box's default component is a div. see [material-ui Box](https://material-ui.com/components/box/)

A div's default behavior is to stretch horizontally across the available space. That is why your Box is stretching horizontally. [Where is the default size of a div element defined or calculated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35010655/where-is-the-default-size-of-a-div-element-defined-or-calculated)

The minHeight: "100vh" style you are applying to the Box is telling it to stretch across the available vertical space. That is why your Box is stretching vertically.
see [Fun with Viewport Units](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/)

Perhaps using the Grid component as a wrapper will give you what you are looking for

```
   <Grid container className={props.classes.sectionStyle}
                          direction="column"
                          justify="space-evenly"
                          alignItems="center"
   >
       <Grid item>
           <Form />
       </Grid>
   </Grid>
```

This would change your code to be:

```
import React from "react";
import {Grid} from '@material-ui/core';
import Form from "./components/Form";

const sectionStyle = {
  height: "100vh",

  backgroundImage:
    "url('www.blablabla.com/img.jpg') ",

  backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
  backgroundSize: "cover"
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Grid style={sectionStyle}
        container
        direction="column"
        justify="space-evenly"
        alignItems="center"
    >
      <Grid item>
        <Form />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use `pseudo` elem like`:after` and `:before`

Here is an example.

```css
.background-filter::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: .8;
    background: red;
}

.background-filter {
  position: relative;
}

.background {
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/62/Kermit_the_Frog.jpg');
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.background span{
position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    }
```

```html
<div class="background background-filter"><span>Hello World I am text with background blur</span></div>
```

> Do what ever you want to apply to `::after` wont effect the form above