# Why is grid-template-rows 1fr not taking the whole available screen?

Tags: html, css, css-grid, grid-layout

This is my `html` :

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
  <div>Five</div>
</div>
```

and my `css` :

```css
#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

#wrapper {
  border: 2px solid #f76707;
  
}

#wrapper > div {
  border: 2px solid #ffa94d;
}
```

And this is the result :

[image]

There is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chapo/2q7Lfz1j/) for it.

How come the rows are not stretched to occupy all the available screen space ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because your `wrapper` doesnt have full screen height. refactor your code like this:

```
#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  height:100vh;
}
```

Comment: but why do I need to adjust the vertical viewport and not the horizontal one though ?

Comment: check this answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/35010790/10239185]