# Angular 2 div scroll event, height is null

Tags: angular

Angular 2 scroll event getting height is null.

```
[sample]: https://plnkr.co/edit/RZSQkd0nqolYv3NBvArG?p=preview
```

Comment: Why do you expect the attribute `height` to be set? What value do you expect to get?

Comment: nope i don't want to set height, i want get height of that div which has scroll, based on that i will write logic like infinite scroll logic.

Answer (score 1):

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/U36beuh9AJiEXYZoURTW?p=preview)

Seems what you want is

```
  onScroll(){
    console.log('clientHeight: ' + this._el.clientHeight);
    console.log('offsetHeight: ' + this._el.offsetHeight);
  }
```

See also [Get div height with plain JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615552/get-div-height-with-plain-javascript)

`getAttribute()` reads attributes. Attributes are visible in the DOM. `clientHeight` is a property.

See also [Properties and Attributes in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/properties-and-attributes-in-html)

Comment: And how to implement,

basic of infinite scroll.

[https://plnkr.co/edit/RZSQkd0nqolYv3NBvArG?p=preview]

Comment: I haven't done an infinite scroll implementation myself yet. If you have more concrete questions I might be able to help but this is too broad. No idea where to start.

Comment: I just started learning angular 2. it will be helpful for beginners. 

i have query.
i want to create a directive like scroller, that will bound to my component,

my component has service logic to update the data which has scroller.

but my scroller has only event of scrolling up and scrolling down, how do i bind component method to scroller directive scroll event.

Comment: Sorry, I think that's too broad for StackOverflow. Acually I don't even know what a scroller should do exactly. You might have a look at https://github.com/angular/material2 or https://github.com/justindujardin/ng2-material if they contain something like that.