# Store div properties into var

Tags: html, var

How to get the height of a div and store into a variable?

```
.top {
    content:url(../images/top480.jpg);
    z-index:0;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000000;
    width:100%;
}
/* The weight is variable, is not fixed*/
```

I am trying something like this:

```
var hou = $(".top").width();
window.alert(hou);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get div height with plain JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615552/get-div-height-with-plain-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use $(".top").height();

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Is there a jsfiddle you can link to? Or some kind of test environment.

Comment: Is this fiddle what you are looking for?
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jaspercreel/zwwompye/)