# Regex: Get value of height from a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like `.hello-world-chat-size {height: 350px !important;}` and I want to extract the value of `height` attribute i.e `350`. I tried this regex `/^height\:(.*)$/gm` but cant get any result.

Comment: Because `^` matches the start of string and `$` matches the end of string. You can just use `/height:\s*(\d+)px/`, or anything similar.

Comment: out of curiosity, if you want an attribute of an element, why not just grab that instead of regex a string? (offsetHeight or clientHeight http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615552/get-div-height-with-plain-javascript)

Comment: @Nikki9696 I have extracted the above string using `getElementsByTagName().innerHTML` so it is a string

Comment: It's usually better to use the DOM if you can, and you do have the element in the DOM if you used getElementsByTagName. Just a suggestion. Happy Friday!   =)  "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems."  https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/

Comment: Yah,, U are correct. I'll research getElementsByTagName a bit and will try to eliminate the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occurs because `^` matches the start of string and `$` matches the end of string. Actually, `(.*)$` matches the whole rest of the line, but since the beginning of the pattern did not match, there was no match at all. You can just use

```
/height:\s*(\d+)px/
```

or

```
/height:\s*(\d+)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fB2rY7/1)

**Details**:

- `height:` - a literal substring `height:`
- `\s*`  - zero or more whitespace symbols
- `(\d+)` -  1 or more digits
- `px` - a literal string `px` (actually, it is redundant, but just in case you might have other value without `px`, you might keep it to be as explicit as can be)

JS demo:

```js
var re = /height:\s*(\d+)px/; 
var str = '.hello-world-chat-size {height: 350px !important;}';
var m = str.match(re);
if (m) {
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```

Comment: what about `.equal-height-div {width:123px;}`?

Comment: That is a bit different, what do you want to extract from it? `123`? A mere `/width:(\d+)/` will do. Add more context for a safer match. Say, you can add `{`: `/{width:(\d+)/`. Or if there can be whitespaces: `/{\s*width\s*:\s*(\d+)/`