# How to get inner HTML content height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to get inner html height by JavaScript. Suppose I have

```
<div>Content</div>
```

either if the div font size has increased or many divs nested inside the parent, how do I get the height of parent div?

edit: even if the nested div has border and padding too.

Comment: if jquery is acceptable, then `.height()` function

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15615701/1252056

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get div height with plain JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615552/get-div-height-with-plain-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS / JavaScript - How do you get the rendered height of an element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526347/css-javascript-how-do-you-get-the-rendered-height-of-an-element)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If it must be in vanilla JS...

```
var height = document.getElementById('content').clientHeight;
```

That will not include any borders or scrollbars in the element, just padding.  If you want to include borders and scrollbars you may use `offsetHeight` instead.

Comment: `clientHeight` include just the padding, and `offsetHeight` includes padding, borders, and scrollbars

Answer (score 26):

The accepted answer is incorrect in the case that the parent element has a height of `0`, and you want the height of the content within it (which is what I believe the OP was asking for). In that case, `scrollHeight` is the property you want.

```js
const divInnerContentHeight = document.querySelector('div').scrollHeight;
```

Using `clientHeight` or `offsetHeight` would return `0`;

Comment: This is the best answer, it allows you to get the inner height without knowing anything about the contents.

Comment: This is the right answer..

Answer (score 2):

Use clientHeight and getElementsByTagName div to get spcific div height

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].clientHeight
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/XKoxZw

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
<div id="MyDiv">Content</div>

console.log(document.getElementById("MyDiv").offsetHeight);
```

Answer (score 1):

Include padding and border in your height calculation:

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').offsetHeight;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can you content(ele) scrollheight to height of content.

```
ele.scrollHeight
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 //We can do his using JQuery

    //Returns the element's height
    $('#content').height();
   // Returns the height with padding
    $('#content').innerHeight();
   // Returns the height with padding and border
    $('#content').outerHeight();
   // Returns the height with padding,border and margin
    $('#content').outerHeight(true);
```