# How do you get div height in pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the equivalent to the below code in pure javascript?

```
 $('.div1').height($('.div2').height());
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? (This isn't difficult if you do a little bit of a google search.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get div height with plain JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615552/get-div-height-with-plain-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get the rendered height of an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526347/how-do-you-get-the-rendered-height-of-an-element)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That will be the following:

```
document.querySelector(".div1").style.height = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".div2")).height;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `document.getElementsByClassName`

```
var height = document.getElementsByClassName("div1")[0].style.height;
document.getElementsByClassName("div2")[0].style.height = height;
```

Comment: If the height CSS style is not set, <element>.style.height is an empty string

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all the elements with the class name, setting them all to the desired height. Like this:

```
var div1s = document.getElementsByClassName(".div1");
var height = document.getElementsByClassName(".div2")[0].height;
for (int i = 0; i < div1s.length; i++) {
     div1s[i].height = height;
}
```