# How to get actual height without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var test = document.getElementById('test');
console.log(test.offsetHeight);
```

```html
<div style="height: 30px;" id="test">
  <p>ffffffffff</p>
  <p>gggggggggg</p>
  <p>aaaaaaaaaa</p>
  <p>dddddddddd</p>
</div>
```

As you can see, the content in `test` div is `overflow` and more than `30px`: so how to get accurate height?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get div height with plain JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615552/get-div-height-with-plain-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

```js
var test = document.getElementById('test');
alert(test.scrollHeight);
```

```html
<div style="height: 30px;" id="test">
  <p>ffffffffff</p>
  <p>gggggggggg</p>
  <p>aaaaaaaaaa</p>
  <p>dddddddddd</p>
</div>
```

try `scrollHeight`

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `.clientHeight` or `.offsetHeight;`.

What is the difference?

`.clientHeight` includes padding.

`.offsetHeight` includes padding, scrollBar and borders.

```js
var clientH = document.getElementById('test').clientHeight;
var offsetH = document.getElementById('test').offsetHeight;


console.log(clientH);
console.log(offsetH);
```

```html
<div style="height: 30px;" id="test">
  <p>ffffffffff</p>
  <p>gggggggggg</p>
  <p>aaaaaaaaaa</p>
  <p>dddddddddd</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('test')).height
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var test = document.getElementById('test');
alert(test.clientHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var offsetHeight = document.getElementById('test').offsetHeight;
```