# How do I set the height of a div using math in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to be able to type in the aspect ratio for the div and not have to manually calculate and input the height in the CSS each time.

It's not a big deal, but it would be more elegant this way and I want to learn what the mistake was for future reference.

```js
window.onload = function() {
 var x = document.getElementById("movie");
 var ar = 1.33;
    x.style.height = x.style.height / ar;
};
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}

#movie {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: navy;
}

.t {
  -webkit-animation: change 48s infinite;
  -moz-animation: change 48s infinite;
  -o-animation: change 48s infinite;
  animation: change 48s infinite;
}

.name {
 font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: gold;
 text-align: center;
 letter-spacing: 3px;
 margin-top: 36px;
 opacity: 0.3;
}

@keyframes change {
  from {
    background-color: black;
  }
  to {
    background-color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="movie" class="t"></div>
  <p class="name">Pedro Costa</p>
</body>
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Along with @lumio, WHERE is the error message thrown?

Comment: movie is a variable ?

Comment: I fixed it, no error anymore. But it still doesn't work. @GeekSilva no, it's the id name, fixed it now.

Comment: Likely because `x.style.height` is returning a string like "100px", which doesn't do much when divided by 1.33. Review some articles about getting the current values for things like height like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15615552/215552.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x.style.height` is an empty string because it's looking at the `#movie` element's `style` attribute (which is initially empty). The error likely stems from attempting to divide a string by a number.

To figure out what styles are applied via a style sheet or `<style>` block, you could look at [`document.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle). However, where you're interested in the height of the element, you might find it preferable to look at the element's `offsetHeight` property instead. Once you've computed the new height, you'll also need to make sure you append the correct units (e.g. `px`) before adding it as a style to the element.

```
x.style.height = x.offsetHeight / ar + 'px';
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
 var x = document.getElementById('movie');
 var ar = 1.33;
    x.style.height = x.offsetHeight / ar + 'px';
};
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}

#movie {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: navy;
}

.t {
  -webkit-animation: change 48s infinite;
  -moz-animation: change 48s infinite;
  -o-animation: change 48s infinite;
  animation: change 48s infinite;
}

.name {
 font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: gold;
 text-align: center;
 letter-spacing: 3px;
 margin-top: 36px;
 opacity: 0.3;
}

@keyframes change {
  from {
    background-color: black;
  }
  to {
    background-color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="movie" class="t"></div>
  <p class="name">Pedro Costa</p>
</body>
```

Alternatively, you could seed the `#movie` element's height as an inline style, but this is generally considered poorer practice.

```
x.style.height = parseInt(x.style.height) / ar + 'px';
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
 var x = document.getElementById('movie');
 var ar = 1.33;
    x.style.height = parseInt(x.style.height) / ar + 'px';
};
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}

#movie {
  width: 200px;
  background: navy;
}

.t {
  -webkit-animation: change 48s infinite;
  -moz-animation: change 48s infinite;
  -o-animation: change 48s infinite;
  animation: change 48s infinite;
}

.name {
 font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: gold;
 text-align: center;
 letter-spacing: 3px;
 margin-top: 36px;
 opacity: 0.3;
}

@keyframes change {
  from {
    background-color: black;
  }
  to {
    background-color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="movie" class="t" style="height: 100px;"></div>
  <p class="name">Pedro Costa</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS actually has a calc method that you can use.

```
width: calc(100% - 100px);
```

Ex: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_func_calc

Comment: You should specify if this is CSS3, and if it's not available in Internet Explorer especially.

Comment: @krillgar It's supported perfectly well in IE.

Comment: When I use `height: calc(700px / 1.33)`, it makes height be about 395 pixels, whereas 700/1.33 is 526.

Comment: @torazaburo That's good. However, this is still a mostly link-only answer. Nothing is explained about how it works here.