# get and set height of element

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Hello I write in es6 module to set in all elements (`.product-category__item`) the same height but I can't get any height :/

```
var measureElements = document.querySelectorAll('.product-category__item');
for(let item of measureElements) {
    console.log(item.style.height)  // return nothing
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uba46k0e/

Comment: The elements in your fiddle don't have any `style` attributes, so it accurately returns the empty string for them. What did you expect?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615552/get-div-height-with-plain-javascript) will be helpful.