# Clear fixed header with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, css-position

I have a site here: http://staging.seedcreativeacademy.co.uk/blog/ where I have fixed the header.

At the moment, on other pages I have added a top margin in manually to clear the fixed header (so the content doesnt fall behind the header).

However this is getting a little complex so I'm looking for a site wide fix. I came across a way of doing out in JQuery, like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    header_height = $(".site-header").height();
    $(".site-inner").css("margin-top", header_height);
});
```

However, this isn't working. I think it's not working because the fixed .site-header doesn't actually have an assigned height. I think the height is based on the contents and the padding / margin of the contents.

So, is there anyway around this? the header is fixed on ever page so I'm trying to figure out a site wide solution...

Also, the amount of margin needed changes as the pages shrinks for different devices, currently fixed with media queries.

So I guess I need something that can constantly measure the .site-header and apply that number of margin to the .site-inner...

I'm open to any other ideas if this isn't the correct way to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to take outerHeight() instead of height().

Here is your updated code which you need to apply:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    header_height = jQuery(".site-header").outerHeight();
    jQuery(".site-inner").css("margin-top", header_height);
 });
```

I have checked by executing above code from console in your site and its working fine.

Let me know if you need more help.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry to ask again @Addweb, but is there anything I can add to that to exclude a certain page? My contact page: http://staging.seedcreativeacademy.co.uk/contact/ I would like it not to effect that as the first thing here is not the site-inner but the map...

Comment: fixed the other issue with: .page-id-102 .site-inner {
  margin-top: 0 !important;
} :)

Answer (score 1):

use below function for get client height or off set Height of header part

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   // headerHeight = $('.site-inner').height();
    var clientheaderHeight = document.getElementsByClassName('site-inner').clientHeight; //includes padding.
    //Or
    //var offsetHeight = document.getElementsByClassName('site-inner').offsetHeight; // includes padding, scrollBar and borders.

   jQuery('.site-inner').css('margin-top', clientheaderHeight);
});
```

more info here : [Get div height with plain JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615552/get-div-height-with-plain-javascript)

Comment: Thanks @Shital - However this is not working and I'm getting the following error in console: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById('.site-inner').clientHeight')

Comment: please check now

Comment: Different erros in the console: TypeError: $ is not a function. (In '$(window)', '$' is undefined) - Sorry I dont know enough javascript to troubleshoot errors!! :)

Comment: use jQuery instead of $

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just apply the height of your header as a top margin to your .site-inner class? This would fix all pages on your site.

```
.site-inner {
    margin-top: 149px;
}
```

and for mobile screen size header:

```
@media (max-width: 859px) {
    margin-top: 93px;
}
```

Comment: I think I can, however, as it changes on lots and lots of different screen sizes I was hoping for a more dynamic solution, hence trying JS...

Comment: It appears to only be 1 of the 2 sizes as above