# How to get height from html div element?

Tags: html, typescript, angular5

I am using angular 5 where in a component I have one method

```
onFullScreen : function (event){ console.log(event[0]) }
```

Here, when I do `console.log(event[0])`, this will return this

[image]

This returns a HTMLDivElement, now I want to get the height property in my `onFullScreen()` method. How to get it?

Comment: See similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615552/get-div-height-with-plain-javascript

Comment: Can you do console..log(event[0].childNodes) and let me know what you get?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to get the height of an element (and lots of other layout-related properties) is to use `getBoundingClientRect` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).

So you can do this:

```
const height = event[0].getBoundingClientRect().height;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var height = document.getElementById('element').style.height;
```

Since the height is defined in inline styles for this element, this would work.

Warning: this does not work if height is not explicitly defined in css but calculated based on content or outer box.

Comment: there's nothing like rectangle here, I made rectangle in image so that it will be easy to recognize where I am getting the HTMLDivElement and height property.

Comment: This wouldn't work. `style.height` only would return the `height` property set in the `style` attribute. It may return pixels, a percentage, or, probably, nothing.