# How to get the new size of a dynamically sized div?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a div that slides up from the bottom of my pagewhen a button is clicked. i do this using a css transition and changing the css "top" attribute of the div. works fine if the div size never changes. So for example if the div is 400px high, i just move it up 400px and it's now in position. cool.

BUT... what if the div has dynamically generated content and will be a different height every time? how can i figure out how much to move the div up in order to be 100% showing?

so in pseudo code i want something like

```
function movemydiv() {

var howMuchToMoveIt = ??? (somehow getting the dynamic containers height)

document.getelementbyId("mydiv").style.top = bottomOfScreen - howMuchToMoveIt
```

any tips on most straightforward way to do this??

Comment: This might help 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615552/get-div-height-with-plain-javascript

Comment: consider posting your `HTML` structure and the `JavaScript` part that assigns a dynamic size to the `div`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either [`clientHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight) or [`offsetHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight) to measure the height of your div. 
Both clientHeight and offSetHeight include padding , but offsetHeight will also take into account borders and horizontal scrollbars (if rendered) - see MDN link.

So your js would be something like:

```
var howMuchToMoveIt = document.getElementById('mydiv').clientHeight;
```

The var will then contain the height of your element.

Hope this helps

Comment: As alternative could also use [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).