# Get css class property using react app. Is JQuery Necessary?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs, properties

I have a css class with a property, like:

```
myClass {
    height: 100px;
}
```

How do i get that height in javascript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get div height with plain JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615552/get-div-height-with-plain-javascript)

Comment: No, i want to get height from class, not from div.

Comment: Well, you'd get the height by getting the div with that class.  You can't read a css stylesheet with js.

Comment: Neither with Jquery?

Comment: This might be what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324486/how-do-you-read-css-rule-values-with-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you read CSS rule values with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324486/how-do-you-read-css-rule-values-with-javascript)