# Is there a way to use an "if" statement and see if a divs height is larger or smaller than a specific amount of px in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to use an "if" statement and see if a divs height is larger or smaller than a specific amount of px in javascript?

For example, can you do something like this?:

```
if (document.getElementById('mydiv').style.height < 50px) {}
```

I've tried to use 50px, 50, "50px", "50 px"....

Comment: You could try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615552/get-div-height-with-plain-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `clientHeight` or `offsetHeight` to the get the height of the element and then use it in if statement.

**[clientHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight)**

> The Element.clientHeight read-only property is zero for elements with no CSS or inline layout boxes; otherwise, it's the inner height of an element in pixels. It includes padding but excludes borders, margins, and horizontal scrollbars (if present).

**[offsetHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight)**

> The HTMLElement.offsetHeight read-only property returns the height of an element, including vertical padding and borders, as an integer.

**Example:**

```js
(function() {
        let element = document.getElementById('content');
        if(element.clientHeight < 20) {
          console.log("Client height is less than 20, and height is: ", element.clientHeight);
        } else {
          console.log("Client height is greater than 20", element.clientHeight);
        }
      })();
```

```html
 <div id="content" style="height: 19px;">Some div</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var divElement = document.querySelector(".app");       
var elemHeight = divElement.offsetHeight;
var exampleHeight = 60;
if(elemHeight > 60){
  console.log('enough');
 }else{
  console.log('not enough');
}

console.log(elemHeight);
```

```html
<div class="app">
<p>this is simple text</p>
</div>
```

elaborate your question clearly. for exact result. I think you want that

Comment: and if is a statement.

Comment: Code-only answers can be greatly improved by elaborating on the code. Why does it work? What is offsetHeight? Are there alternatives? See Sohail’s answer for an example.