# How to access or read the css property value in angular typescript file

Tags: css, angular

html file:

```
<div #sampleComponent class="cdt-sample-component"
[ngStyle]="{'height': (view_height) + 'px'}" >
  <app-component></app-component>
</div>
```

css file:

```
.cdt-sample-component {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    height: calc(100% / 3);
}
```

}

ts file:

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    logger.info("NativeElement height " + this.renderer.selectRootElement(this.metricsComponent['nativeElement']).getAttribute('height'));
    }
```

The above log print in ts file is returning null for "height" attribute.
I am using angular 7.

I would like to get the value of "height" attribute defined in css in div element "cdt-sample-component", somehow i am getting null. Can you please answer on how to get the height attribute value in ts file which is defined in css file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use `ViewChild` to get a reference to the element and read it's `clientHeight` or `offsetHeight` property.

**Controller**

```js
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";

export class SomeComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild("sampleComponent") sampleComponent: ElementRef<any>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.sampleComponent.nativeElement.clientHeight);
  }
}
```

For `clientHeight` vs `offsetHeight` see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15615701/6513921

Comment: Thanks a lot for immediate response. I am able to see the clientHeight value in ts file. I am curious to know if there is a way to get or access any css property value in ts file, just an example, if i have "height1" property in css file:

Comment: @vrreddy1234: You could probably use `getComputedStyle()`. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6338234/6513921

Comment: What if the markup is still not loaded into DOM, I just want to get some CSS property for selector in my Angular code?

Comment: @Alexander: If the markup isn't loaded in the DOM yet, then this method cannot be used as the template reference variable would be unavailable for the `@ViewChild()` to find.

Comment: @ruth yeap, i understand. I was planning to find CSS property selector from one of numerous CSS files that are loaded. But seems like this is too complex: I would need to check ALL loaded stylesheets in the query result.

Comment: @Alexander: That could be quite tricky. An inefficient suggestion: [`getComputedStyle(document.body)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle). Then try the [methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration#methods) from the returned `CSSStyleDeclaration` object.