# How do I find the height of a div, without height style in jquery?

Tags: javascript

```js
var div = document.querySelector('#ma_div');
console.log(div.offsetHeight);
console.log(div.getBoundingClientRect().height);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id"ma_div">
<span> bla bla bla bla</span>

</div>
```

I would like to get the height in real time of a div.
Inside my div I have no height from the css.

I would like to know the height of my div, both on computer and telephone.

In this div I have a long text.

```
<div "ma_div">
<span>bla bla bla bla bla</span>
</div>
```

```js
var div = document.querySelector('#ma_div');
console.log(div.offsetHeight);
console.log(div.getBoundingClientRect().height);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div  id="ma_div">
<span> bla bla bla bla</span>
<span> bla bla bla bla</span>
<span> bla bla bla bla</span>
<span> bla bla bla bla</span>
<span> bla bla bla bla</span>
<span> bla bla bla bla</span>
<span> bla bla bla bla</span>
</div>
```

Comment: `"ma_div"` seems the value of an attribute missing. By the way with vanilla js you can use [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to know the exact size and coords used for a given rendered element. In general: [Determining the dimensions of elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Determining_the_dimensions_of_elements)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get div height with plain JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615552/get-div-height-with-plain-javascript)

Comment: You mean... `<div id="ma_div">` ?

Comment: yes exact id="ma_div"